# JSP context root shows empty page

Tags: jsp, servlets

OpenJDK8 Java EE project using Tomcat 8.5 on Eclipse.

Let's say my project's context root is "/sample".

There is no problem presenting pages with URL "/sample/index.jsp".

If the URL's very end is "/sample"(which is context root),however, it shows an empty blank page.

I tried cleaning project, re-starting server and checking web.xml files but no error was found yet.

This has happened after merging with my teammates.

Comment: Does your `web.xml` file have a `<welcome-file-list>`? If not, the default `<welcome-file-list>` that is in the `TOMCAT_ROOT/conf/web.xml` file is the following files, in this order: `index.html`, `index.htm`, `index.jsp`. --- If you have a blank `index.html` file, that would be why the `index.jsp` file doesn't show.

Comment: @Andreas Yup I tried removing index.html, index.htm except index.jsp from `<welcome-file-list>`s that are under Tomcat and my project's WEB-INF.

Comment: You should not modify the `web.xml` from tomcat. Just add your content to your `index.jsp`/`index.html`/...

Comment: @dan1st I got the first loading page's contents inside of `index.jsp` file.

Comment: @BalusC Thanks but I checked it already.

Answer (score 0):

I exported the project and deleted from Eclipse.
Then I imported the project again and edit `web.xml`.
Hope this works for the ones who are struggling with the sample problem.